# Is it a good idea to store classes as settings items in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design

I am doing this project in c# and when designing a database, i am  using a rule that each class is basically sql table (at least the class that has to be persisted).

Since some classes are purely used to define business settings and the classes are rather flat, I am curios does it make any sense to do something like this..

Transform business layer class

```
class Contact
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
public bool AcceptsTextMessages {get;set;}
public bool AllowedHoursForTextMessagesStart {get;set;}
public bool AllowedHoursForTextMessagesEnd {get;set;}
public List<DayOfWeek> SendMessagesOnlyOnWorkdays {get;set;}
}
```

to a data layer class that look something like (and persist it in sql)

```
public Settings
{
public ID {get;set}
public Name {get;set}
public Value {get;set;}
}
```

with real life data

```
ID   Name                                Value
1    Name                                John Doe
2    PhoneNumber                         01234657
3    ExceptsTextMessages                 true
4    AllowedHoursForTextMessagesStart    0
5    AllowedHoursForTextMessagesEnd      24
6    SendMessagesOnlyOnDays              1,2,3,4,5
```

The primary reason for this is to have one settings table instead of having as many tables as classes, possibly easier class modification, easier manipulation of properties between classes (in case there is a business logic need to move one property from one class to another)

Comment: Given that different users might have different settings, the first method might be simpler to implement.  You really only want to use the second method (formally called entity-attribute-value, EAV) when you have too many columns for a table or the columns themselves significant differ from entity to entity.

Answer (score 1):

Decomposing your objects into IDs and attribute-value pairs is one of those techniques that's *sometimes* extremely useful. EAV data is much more complicated to manage than a flat table with individual columns, so it's not something to implement lightly.

Given what you've posted, I probably wouldn't. All the fields you have seem reliably relevant to being-a-contact and unlikely to require changing around dynamically in production (since one starts or stops accepting text messages, rather than ascending to a plane of existence where text messages are epistemologically irrelevant).

Even if it made sense to represent certain fields as pairs, I'd only do it for those fields: keep a users table with a primary key and the essential data, then put the rest off in an EAV table with a foreign key relationship to users.